# New to jquery trying to drag my square around with no success here's my code

Tags: jquery

Hi trying to make my square draggable but with no success. Is the problem with my script? or did I miss spell something? 
thanks

```
<style>

  #square {

          background-color:red;
          width:200px;
          height:200px;
  }


</style>
```

```
  <div id="square"></div>

 <script

 $("#square").draggable();

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery UI?

See: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

You need to initialise both jQuery and jQuery UI:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
</script>
<div id="draggable">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Checkout this CodePen with both jQuery and jQuery UI being initialised:

https://codepen.io/dammeul/pen/JXpPwe